# js Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript

```
var a = {
    fun:function(){
        alert(1);
    }
}
a.fun = function(){
    a.fun();
    alert(2);
}
a.fun();
```

I want to change the function a.fun but call the origin one

Comment: so store the original somewhere else before you change it

Comment: The function `a.fun` is overriding the previous function, so you're calling the same function recursively indefinitely. Use different names for the functions, `var a = {
    fun1:function() {
        alert(1);
    }
};
a.fun2 = function() {
    a.fun1();
    alert(2);
};
a.fun2();`

Comment: because you have an infinite recursive method call

Comment: You could write your program more concisely as `function a() { a(); } a();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to override the existing function and call the original function back from the overridden instance, then you need to store the reference to the old method like

```js
var a = {
  fun: function() {
    snippet.log(1);
  }
};
(function(a) {
  var old = a.fun;
  a.fun = function() {
    old.apply(this, arguments);
    snippet.log(2);
  }
})(a);
a.fun();
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```